# Suffixes -unt and -ut-

Tags: translation

I just discovered the two conditional suffixes on vortaro.net:

- [-ut-](http://vortaro.net/#-ut-) : *la ofendutoj pardonu!*
- [-unt-](http://vortaro.net/#-unt-) : *eĉ perfiduntan mi ŝin volas mia!*

But I don't understand the given exemples. Can someone help me translate, please ?

Comment: I comment instead of answering, as it is no direct answer to your question: The conditional suffixes are generally seen as being against the norm (the Fundamento grammar, §6, fixes the morpholgy of the verb; besides that it would be illogical to put mood into a verbal form that expresses relative time), and they are hardly ever used (and then often in a joking tone). I highly recommend not to use them at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> la ofendutoj pardonu

According to the definition in PIV, and much like other participles, *ofenduto* means *iu, kiun oni ofendus*; just like *ofendito* means *iu, kiun oni ofendis*. Thus *la ofendutoj pardonu* means more or less ‘Those who would be offended should forgive.’

> eĉ perfiduntan mi ŝin volas mia!

<s>I have no idea what this means either, even without the -*unt*-participle.</s> But *perfidunta* means ‘such that it would betray’. So *perfidunta homo* = *homo, kiu perfidus iun*.

EDIT: As [Vincent Oostelbos](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/users/416/vincent-oostelbos) pointed out, the example sentence probably should be parsed as follows:

> Mi volas ŝin, eĉ perfiduntan, mia!

Thus this would mean something like: ‘I want her to be mine, even if she would betray me.’

Comment: I think perfidunta(n) would be something like 'such that one would betray', as you wrote. This would describe the 'ŝin' in the sentence, so the whole thing would be something like: Even (with her) being in a state where she would betray (me), I want her as mine! A more natural translation would be, Even if she would betray me, I want her to be mine!

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense. The sentence is very weirdly phrased so I really could not parse it, but thank you! I think that makes sense and I'll add it to the answer for completeness sake.